# Android: Why am I getting a null pointer error for my button when I use a different XML file?

Tags: android, xml, button

I am getting a null pointer error when I try referring to a button that is not in my main XML file -- it's in another XML file. The reason why I want it in another XML file is so that the button only shows up when the user presses a MenuItem, which will the prompt them to the page with the button.

How can I access a button that is not in my main.xml?

here is what I have

```
 @Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {

              case R.id.timer_icon:
              Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timer_button);
              startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//error occurs here

                  public void onClick(View view) {//do stuff }
               });

               break;
    }
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timer_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="timer text"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/timer_button"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
        android:text="timer button text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If it matters, the above Java code is in my Main activity.

Comment: Just put it in your main xml, and hide it by default. Then set the visibility to `VISIBLE` in `onMenuItemClick`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of placing it in another xml file, have you consider using `View.GONE` as the visibility of the button in the same xml file?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE

> This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout
>   purposes.

So using the attribute to set the button to `View.GONE` and then when the user click on the menu item, change the visibility to `View.VISIBLE`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

I just created a new Activity and linked the java and xml code to that new activity. Works like a charm now!

Thanks for your inputs tho!